# Issue with browse and upload new thumbnail in the template of CQ 5.5

Tags: aem

I have provided thumbnail image for my templates. The thumbnail has jcr:content with property as below
name    jcr:data
type    boolean
value   view

On double click view we get a browse option to upload new image from file system. But on selecting an image and clicking "OK" button the window isn't closing, though the new image gets uploaded in the thumbnail. And thus we have to close it either by clicking the "cancel" button or the 'X' (close) button.

Any solution to fix the "OK" issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the browser show any Javascript issues?
Does the CQ error log tell you anything?

Comment: Yes. It is showing js error  SyntaxError: syntax error  <pre></pre>   ext-all-debug.js (line 11527, col 1). The corresponding line is as below:  Ext.util.JSON = new (function(){
  ...............
  ..............
        doDecode = function(json){
            return eval("(" + json + ')');    
        },
        .............
  ...........
}   On the return statement.

Comment: Ok anything inside the CQ error.log? Have you tried to debug into the page using firebug or chrome debugger to find out why there is an issue with the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in CQ, because I have the same problem. I don't think CRXDE Lite can handle uploading an image directly. I would recommend creating a new package with a filter for just that image (/apps/myproject/templates/htmlpage/thumbnail.png). Build the package and then download it. Extract the package and replace the image with the new thumbnail. Rezip the package and upload it to your CQ instance, then click the install button. This workaround will let you update the image.

There is also a way to directly access the JCR filesystem. In Mac OSX I open up Finder and hit CMD-K to connect to the CQ instance directly. Then I can just drop the new image in directly. I'm not sure what environment you're working in, so your mileage with this approach may vary.

Comment: Well moch,
I believe package download-update-upload to CRXlite is a bit tedious task esp. when there are many templates in your application.
If yours is CQ5.5 then as from the original Question posted, I have already mentioned that the new image is getting updated though the window isnt closing on click of "OK"

Wll if anybody knows how to rectify above issue ?

Comment: So are you saying the image is correctly uploaded but the dialog box won't successfully close? Because I tried it and it didn't look like it uploaded the new image. Thus I proposed a couple of alternate methods for doing so.

Comment: Yea Moch, the image is uploaded correctly but the dialog box isnt closing. This is coming for CQ5.5. For 5.4 there isnt even the browse option available, I think Adobe had come up with solution in 5.5 for this flaw in 5.4 but now they need further rectification in coming versions.

Comment: Yeah, this bug is still there in 5.6. Have you submitted it to Adobe?